# Direct3D ID3DXFont->DrawText Crash on Windows XP

Tags: windows, fonts, directx

I'm trying to load a font from a file and then use it in Direct3D, and it works perfectly on my Windows 7 machine, but if I try it on an XP SP2 machine, the first call to `DrawText` will return 0 (meaning it failed), and the second time it tries will cause the program to crash.

Are there some restrictions with imported fonts in Direct3D on Windows XP? Is there a way I can get some useful error code, since `DrawText` returning 0 isn't very helpful on its own.

For reference, here's my font importing code:

```
if (AddFontResourceEx("ttfFiles/tf2Build.ttf", FR_PRIVATE, 0) == 0) {
    // Throw exception.
}
```

And here's how I create the `ID3DXFont` object (which also returns without a problem):

```
HRESULT result = D3DXCreateFont(
    d3dDevice_,
    height,
    0, 
    isBolded ? FW_BOLD : FW_NORMAL,
    0,
     false,
    DEFAULT_CHARSET,
    OUT_DEFAULT_PRECIS,
    DEFAULT_QUALITY,
    FF_DONTCARE,
    name.c_str(),
    &d3dFont );

if ( FAILED( result ) ) {
    // Throw exception.
}
```

**Edit:** I managed to get it to occur under a debugger in XP, and here's the quite scary error that appears:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.AccessViolationException' occured in DirectFont.exe
>   Additional information: Attempted to read or write protected memory. This is often an indication that other memory is corrupt.

And here is the stack trace:

> usp10.dll!ClientData::GetOtlTable()  + 0x35 bytes
>   usp10.dll!otlResourceMgr::getOtlTable()  + 0x7a bytes
>   usp10.dll!SubstituteOtlChars()  + 0x1af bytes
>   usp10.dll!OtlShape()  + 0x3c5 bytes
>   D3DX9_43.dll!D3DXCore::CFont::DrawTextAW()  + 0x5aa bytes 
>   D3DX9_43.dll!D3DXCore::CFont::DrawTextA()  + 0x26 bytes

Comment: What does your actual draw code look like? Does it work with other fonts? Are you sure it's loaded the font correctly? You should be using the `SUCCEEDED(hr)` and `FAILED(hr)` macros, as `== 0` does not always indicate success or failure. The exact return value is rather important.

Comment: What is the call stack of the crash?

Comment: peachykeen: `AddFontResourceEx` doesn't return an HRESULT, it returns the number of fonts that were added, or zero if it fails.

Comment: Martyn Lovell: I don't have the call stack yet, because I can't install VC++ 2010 on XP (it requires SP3, which appears to fix the crash, but I can't expect everyone to install it). I'll work on getting it. Edit: just to clarify, I know it's the `DrawText` call because I did some old-style output debugging.

Comment: Martyn Lovell: I've added the stack trace. The error message seems to be more useful, but I'm still at a loss.

Comment: You don't have a symbol path set for OS symbols, so the stack is useless. The basic step for Windows debugging is to use Windows symbols. recent versions of VS make it easy to do this by default (see the debug symbols dialog).

Comment: Martyn Lovell: Sorry about that; I've updated the stack trace to include the symbols.

Comment: I know this is a really old post but I'm curious- did you ever solve this problem?

Comment: Sorry to bear bad news, but no, I never did figure it out. I switched to OpenGL for my application. An alternative that would work on XP would probably be to use Freetype with D3D, but then you have to do a lot of your text stuff manually. Good luck!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is probably in the drawing loop, rather than the initialization. Place a breakpoint at the drawtext call, and look for any invalid parameters at the second call.

Comment: I'd think that if it were invalid parameters, it wouldn't work on either machine, but it runs perfectly on my Windows 7 PC even if I use DirectX Debug Runtime and have it spout all possible warnings.